# Gluon switch scene on custom event

Tags: android, javafx, gluon

I try to switch the scene of a Gluon application when a custom event is fired.

When I call

```
MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView(SECONDARY_VIEW);"
```

I get the error

> Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = Thread-6

This is the listener that handles the custom event

```
ParallelServerInterface.setLoginResponseListener(new LoginResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void loginResponseReceived(LoginResponse loginResponse) {
            Map<String, String> source = (Map<String, String>) loginResponse.getSource();
            boolean status = source.get("status").equals("true");

            if (status) {
                MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView(SECONDARY_VIEW);
            }
        }
    });
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: It looks like you are doing this from a background thread. You can use `Platform.runLater(() -> {... switchView...});` to queue the process to be done in the JavaFX application thread.

Comment: @JoséPereda, that was it. Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any call to `MobileApplication.getInstance()::switchView` should happen in the JavaFX Application thread, as it basically involves changes in the scenegraph.

Roughly, you are removing the old View (which is a `Node`), and adding a new one (another `Node`):

```
glassPane.getChildren().remove(oldNode);
glassPane.getChildren().add(newNode);
```

And as you know, anything related to node manipulation has to be done in the JavaFX Application thread.

It seems the login event is triggered in a background thread, so all you need to do is to queue the view switch to the application thread, using [`Platform.runLater`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)):

```
    @Override
    public void loginResponseReceived(LoginResponse loginResponse) {
        Map<String, String> source = (Map<String, String>) loginResponse.getSource();
        boolean status = source.get("status").equals("true");

        if (status) {
            // switch view has to be done in the JavaFX Application thread:
            Platform.runLater(() ->
                MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView(SECONDARY_VIEW));
        }
    }
```